# Javascript Toggle Check All Nested Array Names

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm having a problem trying to create a Javascript function that checks all the checkboxes in a form.

An example of the checkboxes on my form look like

```
<b>A:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[201][A]"><br>
<b>B:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[201][B]"><br>
<b>C:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[201][C]"><br>
<b>D:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[201][D]"><br>

<b>A:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[500][A]"><br>
<b>B:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[500][B]"><br>
<b>C:</b> <input type="checkbox" name="multipleForms[500][C]"><br>
```

And what I want to do is be able to pass a number such as 201 and 500 into a Javascript function and have all checkboxes with the first array index as that integer be checked.

So, `checkAll(201)` would have the first 4 checkboxes checked and `checkAll(500)` would have the other 3 checkboxes checked.

I would rather not change the names of my checkboxes if that is possible as the stringed indexes are really important for my PHP code.

Thanks in advance.

Also, I would rather have non-jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ? : http://jsfiddle.net/RZPNG/6/

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function check(num) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(checkboxes[i].name.split('[')[1]) === num) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = 'checked';
        }                
    }
}

check(201);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do:

```
function checkBoxes(form, s) {
  var input, inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var re = new RegExp(s);

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) { 
    input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type == 'checkbox' && re.test(input.name)) {
      input.checked = true;
    } else {
      input.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use querySelectorAll, but support isn't that common yet:

```
function checkBoxes(s) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[name*="' + s + '"]');

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    els[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```